# App indexing Api: result callback is not called in OnStop()

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

I am implementing the app indexing API provided by google. As indicated [here](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/publish) I connected the client in onStart() method like this:

```
APP_URI = Uri.parse(baseAppUri + slug);
    WEB_URL = Uri.parse(baseWebUri + slug);
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(Action.TYPE_VIEW, title, WEB_URL, APP_URI);

    // Call the App Indexing API start method after the view has
    // completely
    // rendered
    // Call the App Indexing API view method
    PendingResult<Status> result = AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(mClient, viewAction);

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                CommonLib.ZLog(TAG, "App Indexing API: Recorded " + title + " view successfully.");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "App Indexing API: There was an error recording the view." + status.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

and after the user is done on the page i.e. user presses back button I call AppIndexApi.end in onStop() like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    // Call end() and disconnect the client
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(Action.TYPE_VIEW, title, APP_URI);
    PendingResult<Status> result = AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(mClient, viewAction);

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "App Indexing API: Recorded " + title + " view end successfully.");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "App Indexing API: There was an error recording the  view." + status.toString());
            }
        }
    });

    mClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();

}
```

The problem is that the callback is not being executed. None of the cases in resultcallback are logging the status and execution jumps directly to `mClient.disconnect.`

And the title is not being shown in the search result in google app.

Any idea where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Please try and debug your app stepwise. I had the similar issue and debugging help me find out that there was some exception occurring in some other code due to which the callback was not occuring